# Sequent Calculus for Propositional Intuitionistic Logic and for Propositional Classical Logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus

I'm searching for a book presenting the Sequent Calculus for Propositional Intuitionistic Logic and for Propositional Classical Logic.

In particular I'm searching for a presentation in which the rules of Propositional Classical Logic are the same of the rules of Propositional Intuitionistic Logic plus the Law of Excluded Middle.

Can anyone suggest a book?

Comment: Many books available, e.g. Andrzej Indrzejczak, Sequents and Trees: An Introduction to the Theory and Applications of Propositional Sequent Calculi (2021, Springer)